# command igus-dryve with canopen_motor_node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy there,

i am trying to implement a controller for a [igus-dryve](https://www.igus.de/product/17827) motor drive on ros-kinetic. I am using canopen and the ros_canopen package to communicate over a sysWORXX USBCanmodule 1 with the igus-dryve and have everything setup properly (stepper motor in closed loop beeing controllable over the igus webinterface and set to accept CANopen communication which is wired correctly).

Calling `rosservice call /joint/driver/init` works fine, axis gets reset, return is True and the ros-controllers are loading.

**Here comes my issue:**

1. How do I actually move/command the motor? By setting the actual values of the Object by `rosservice call /joint/driver/setObject` ? Or does the canopen_motor_node take care of all the communication in order to drive the motor? In that case how do I forward a positioning command?
   I tried to call `rostopic pub /lifter_ros/lifter_joint_position_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 1.0"` but no reactions.
2. Additionally i was thinking about if ros_control is really needed in my use-case? igus-dryve already performs a closed-loop control so isn`t ros_control a layer ontop and too much?

Please find attached my controller config:

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
lifter_joint_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: lifter_joint
  required_drive_mode: 1
```

And my node layer:

```
name: igus-dryve 

defaults:
  eds_pkg: lifter_ros
  eds_file: "config/igus_dryve_D1.eds" #electrical desciption file of igus dryve

  #the following scaling is due to 16bit value range limitation of velocity command in vl mode (2)
  #vel_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(vel)*250)"
  #dcf_overlay: # "ObjectID": "ParameterValue" (both as strings)
  #  "604Csub1": "1" # vl dimension factor numerator
  #  "604Csub2": "24000" # vl dimension factor denominator
#defaults: # optional, all defaults can be overwritten per node
  # canopen_chain_node settings ..
  motor_allocator: canopen::Motor402::Allocator # select allocator for motor layer
#motor_layer: #settings passed to motor layer (plugin-specific)
  switching_state: 5 # (Operation_Enable), state for mode switching
  pos_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(pos)*1000)" # rad -> mdeg
  pos_from_device: "deg2rad(obj6064)/1000" # actual position [mdeg] -> rad
  vel_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(vel)*1000)" # rad/s -> mdeg/s
  vel_from_device: "deg2rad(obj606C)/1000" # actual velocity [mdeg/s] -> rad/s
  eff_to_device: "rint(eff)" # just round to integer
  eff_from_device: "0" # unset
nodes:
  lifter_joint:
    id: 2
```

and my launchfile:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- send urdf to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat '$(find lifter_ros)/urdf/lifter.urdf'" />
  <!-- robot state publisher -->
  <node ns="lifter_ros" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="" />
      <!--remap from="joint_states" to="/arm/joint_states"/-->
  </node>

  <node ns="lifter_ros" name="driver" pkg="canopen_motor_node" type="canopen_motor_node" output="screen" clear_params="true" launch-prefix="">
     <rosparam command="load" file="$(find lifter_ros)/config/CANopen_layer.yaml" />
     <rosparam command="load" file="$(find lifter_ros)/config/node_layer.yaml" />
  </node>
  <!-- controllers -->
  <rosparam ns="lifter_ros" command="load" file="$(find lifter_ros)/config/dryve_controller.yaml" />
 <!-- start_controllers -->
  <node ns="lifter_ros" name="lifter_ros_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn joint_state_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

I would highly appreciate your help!

Thanks

**EDIT**
Regarding the controllers: The output says the controller is loaded succesfully, this is also visible when calling the status of the controllers with `rosservice call /lifter_ros/controller_manager/list_controllers` ---> running. Terminal shows following:

```
[ INFO] [1563888510.915229736]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1563888510.915637125]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1563888510.915873954]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
Loaded joint_state_controller
Loaded lifter_joint_position_controller
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
Started ['lifter_joint_position_controller'] successfully
[lifter_ros/controller-4] process has finished cleanly
```

On first startup when calling /driver/init following error message appears: afterwards it works always as described before.

```
Did not receive a response message
[ERROR] [1563892238.035051383]: /home/fhi/flexbin/flexbin_ws/src/ros_canopen/canopen_master/src/sdo.cpp(429): Throw in function void canopen::SDOClient::transmitAndWait(const canopen::ObjectDict::Entry&, const canopen::String&, canopen::String*)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<canopen::TimeoutException> >
std::exception::what: SDO
[canopen::tag_objectdict_key*] = 6061sub0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328745/command-igus-dryve-with-canopen_motor_node/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How do I actually move/command the motor?

You have to publish to the `command` topic of the lifter_joint_position_controller (just like in your example).
If it does not work, please double-check that the controller was actually started.
It looks like you have copied the parameters from the Schunk LWA4 packages, perhaps IGUS needs different settings.

> Additionally i was thinking about if ros_control is really needed in my use-case?

`ros_control` provides a generic controller interface, so all users can choose their controllers.

> igus-dryve already performs a closed-loop control so isn`t ros_control a layer ontop and too much?

`position_controllers/JointPositionController` just forwards the command, i.e., it connects CANopen and ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2019-07-23**:
Thank you for your answer!

*It looks like you have copied the parameters from the Schunk LWA4 packages, perhaps IGUS needs different settings.*

Do you mean the settings of the [canopen_motor_node](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node?distro=melodic)? I am a bit confused of what i would have to actually change...?

I had a look at different examples that use a dcf overlay but have not idea where to start.

Please see Edit for controller up check.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-07-23**:
I was referring to https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots/blob/indigo_dev/schunk_lwa4p/config/arm_driver.yaml#L7.
According to your config, if you command "1.0" [rad], the device will receive the target 57296 [millidegrees]. You should be able to find this in the candump as well.

As a starting point you should first check your unit settings and verify it by reading the joint states in different positions.

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2019-07-23**:
I can't find any message in the candump beeing send when calling /command...

When i rostopic echo /joint_states I just recieve zeros and i can't actually move the motor by hand.
 `header:  seq: 38525 stamp:  secs: 1563890889 nsecs: 267513294 frame_id: '' name: ['lifter_joint'] position: [0.0] velocity: [0.0] effort: [0.0]`

Could you please check my edit above? Seems that the controllers are working properly, arn't they?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-07-23**:
The controllers seem to work, but they just forward message, so it is hard to make them fail.

It looks like your unit settings are wrong: your device is a linear actuator, but your config is for rotary devices. Better check the manual.

You can move the drive to a known location (with the IGUS tool) and check the the position afterwards.

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2019-07-23**:
Thank you for your support!

1. Changed the unit settings to rotary.
2. I moved the motor with the igus-tool and was then calling via /get_object the object 6064 "Position actual value"---> the rostopic echo of the joint states then updates the value.